# Different SELECT's for an INSERT INTO

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I'm trying to have an IF block after an INSERT INTO statement and depending on some conditions, execute a different SELECT that will feed the INSERT INTO.

Here's a (failing) example of what I'm trying to do:

```
INSERT INTO #TempTable (COL1, COL2, COL3)
    IF @VAR = 'YES'
        BEGIN
            SELECT * FROM TABLE
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE REGDATE <= '2015-06-12'
        END
```

But I always end up with this when trying to save the stored proc.

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'
```

I thought of building a string and using `sp_executesql` but I think my initial approach would be less prone to error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option would be to use a `CASE` statement or `IF` statement.  Maybe this?  It is pretty close to what you had:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE1 (a INT, b INT, c INT);
CREATE TABLE TABLE2 (a INT, b INT, c INT);
CREATE TABLE TABLE3 (a INT, b INT, c INT);

INSERT INTO TABLE2 VALUES(1,2,3);
INSERT INTO TABLE3 VALUES(4,5,6);

DECLARE @VAR VARCHAR(MAX) = 'YES'

IF @VAR = 'YES'
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TABLE1
    SELECT * FROM TABLE2
END

ELSE
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TABLE1
    SELECT * FROM TABLE3
END
```

Comment: Can you post an example ? I tried this route as well, but ended with syntax errors too.

Comment: @FrancisDucharme - See new example with IF statement.

Answer (score 1):

It does not work like that. But this is

```
INSERT INTO #TempTable (COL1, COL2, COL3)
SELECT * FROM TABLE
WHERE @VAR = 'YES' OR REGDATE <= '2015-06-12'
```